# How to convert Dictionary <string,List<string>> in C# to csv with keys as headers?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a Dictionary like:

```
{
   key1 : List1 {value1a, value2a},
   key2 : List2 {value1b, value2b},
   ...
}
```

How can I get this into a **csv** that looks like:

```
key1,key2
value1a,value1b
value2a,value2b
...
```

I've tried first converting this to a DataTable but am having trouble with my Linq fundamentals.

```
dataTable.Columns.AddRange(dataDictionary
  .Keys
  .Select(x => new DataColumn(x, dataDictionary[x])).ToArray());
```

```
dataDictionary[x] List<string> can't be converted to System.Type.
```

I've also tried the direct-to-csv route but again I am having trouble remembering how to access the values of the list in LINQ correctly and can't get the keys as headers and the lists into columns:

```
File.WriteAllLines($@"{args[3]}\{args[0]}_{args[1]}_{args[2]}.csv",
  dataDictionary.Select(x => x.Key + ";" + x.Value + ";"));
```

Comment: If you choose to put your fields into a class or structure, you might find [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started#writing-a-csv-file) useful.  However, it seems to be targeted to having hardcoded columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for *csv* (say, csv file), not `DataTable` you can implement csv lines generator straightforward:

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static IEnumerable<string> ToCsv(Dictionary<string, List<String>> data) {
  // Quotation if required: 123,45 -> "123,45"; a"bc -> "a""bc" 
  string Quote(string value) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) 
      ? "" : value.Contains(',') || value.Contains('"') 
      ? "\"" + value.Replace("\"", "\"\'") + "\""
        : value;

  int rowCount = data.Max(pair => pair.Value.Count);

  // Captions
  yield return string.Join(",", data.Select(pair => Quote(pair.Key)));

  // Rows one after one 
  for (int r = 0; r < rowCount; ++r) 
    yield return string.Join(",", data
      .Select(pair => Quote(r < pair.Value.Count ? pair.Value[r] : "")));
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  Dictionary<string, List<string>> data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() {
    { "column1", new List<string>() { "C1_A", "C1_B"} },
    { "column2", new List<string>() { "C2_A", "C2_B", "C2_C"} },
    { "column3", new List<string>() { } },
    { "column4", new List<string>() { "C4_A" } },
  };

  // Generate all lines of the csv and combine them with \r\n:
  string csvText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ToCsv(data));

  Console.Write(csvText);
```

**Outcome:**

```
column1,column2,column3,column4
C1_A,C2_A,,C4_A
C1_B,C2_B,,
,C2_C,,
```

In your case (writing csv into a *file*) you can put it as

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\demo.csv", ToCsv(myDictionary));
```

Comment: amazing, i have not even seen 'yield' before. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are getting below error

```
dataDictionary[x] List<string> can't be converted to System.Type.
```

because, `DataColumn` have multiple overloaded constructor and you are trying call below, which is unable to cast `List<string>` to `Type`.

```
public DataColumn(string columnName, Type dataType)
```

Second, below is the code with assuming that every `List<string>` have same length.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> values = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        values.Add("key1", new List<string>() { "value1a", "value2a" });
        values.Add("key2", new List<string>() { "value1b", "value2b" });

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        dataTable.Columns.AddRange(values.Keys.Select(x => new DataColumn(x)).ToArray());

        var totalColumns = dataTable.Columns.Count;

        for(int i = 0; i < totalColumns; i++)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

            int fieldNumber = 0;
            foreach(var item in values)
            {
                dataRow[fieldNumber] = values[item.Key][i];
                fieldNumber++;
            }

            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }

        dataTable.WriteToCsvFile("D://Test.csv");
    }
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static void WriteToCsvFile(this DataTable dataTable, string filePath)
    {
        var content = dataTable.GenerateCsvBytes();

        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, content);
    }

    public static byte[] GenerateCsvBytes(this DataTable dataTable)
    {
        StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var col in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            fileContent.Append(col.ToString() + ",");
        }

        fileContent.Replace(",", Environment.NewLine, fileContent.Length - 1, 1);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var column in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                fileContent.Append("\"" + column.ToString() + "\",");
            }

            fileContent.Replace(",", Environment.NewLine, fileContent.Length - 1, 1);
        }

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileContent.ToString());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
key1,key2
value1a,value1b
value2a,value2b
```

Comment: Hey Nayan, this works really great. I think this is only adding as many rows as there are columns, though, which works only for this 2x2 example. Can you modify the for loop to fill rows based on the list length?

Comment: @MarkMcGown if the number of keys differs from the list length, how do you get a CSV?

Comment: @NetMage the list length would become the number of rows for the column of which the key of that list is the header.

Comment: @MarkMcGown I'm sorry, I don't find that comprehensible. Perhaps add a couple more examples to your question. In a CSV file, all columns have the same length - and in your CSV file, the # columns equals the number of keys.

Answer (score 0):

This will fail if `data.Keys.Count`!= `data.Values[0].Count`.

```
var keys = data.Keys;
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", keys));
for (int j1 = 0; j1 < keys.Count; ++j1)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", data.Values.Select(v => v[j1])));
```